# [R} Problems in append when sorting elements using for loop

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, append

I'm asked to **only** use for loop to rearrange a vector containing the numbers in random order into descending order.

#please run these two lines of code

```
set.seed(114324)
num <- sample(100,10) #return 96 4 87 11 74  6 37 45 14 26
```

My attempt fails.

```
mx = c(-Inf)

    
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10){
  if (num[i] > mx[j]){
    mx <- append(num[i], mx, i)
  } else {
    mx <- append(mx, num[i])
  }
  }
}
mx
```

My idea is to compare each element of num and arrange the elements one after the other. If the number is greater than the first number in mx, then it will be placed on the leftmost position. If not, it will be placed on the right of the first or subsequent positions of mx.

Grateful if you can advise. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably you can after bubble sort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051165/bubble-sort-using-r-language

Answer (score 2):

You can define a recursion function `f` like below

```
f <- function(v) {
    if (length(v) == 1) {
        return(v)
    }
    mx <- -Inf
    k <- 0
    for (i in seq_along(v)) {
        if (v[i] >= mx) {
            mx <- v[i]
            k <- i
        }
    }
    append(mx, Recall(v[-k]))
}
```

or a non-recursion variant (might be a bit faster)

```
f <- function(v) {
    res <- c()
    repeat {
        if (length(v) == 0) {
            return(res)
        }
        mx <- -Inf
        k <- 0
        for (i in seq_along(v)) {
            if (v[i] >= mx) {
                mx <- v[i]
                k <- i
            }
        }
        res <- append(res, mx)
        v <- v[-k]
    }
}
```

and you will obtain the desired descending order

```
> f(num)
 [1] 96 87 74 45 37 26 14 11  6  4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time knowing Recall(). Let me search what it means.

Comment: @ronzenith `Recall` is a placeholder of the called function, you can replace it with `f` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).
Bubble sort is a bad idea, and I have searched StackExchange for a Q/A mentioning [this job interview question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8) but couldn't find one.

```r
bubble <- function(x) {
  for(m in seq_along(x)[-1L]) {
    for(i in length(x):m) {
      if(x[i - 1L] < x[i]) {
        tmp <- x[i - 1L]
        x[i - 1L] <- x[i]
        x[i] <- tmp
      }
    }
  }
  x
}

set.seed(114324)
num <- sample(100,10) #return 96 4 87 11 74  6 37 45 14 26
bubble(num)
#>  [1] 96 87 74 45 37 26 14 11  6  4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The questions asks for descending order but for the sake of completeness, here is a version that also can sort in ascending order. Its default is descending order.

```r
bubble <- function(x, descending = TRUE) {
  op <- if(descending) `<` else `>`
  for(m in seq_along(x)[-1L]) {
    for(i in length(x):m) {
      if(op(x[i - 1L], x[i])) {
        tmp <- x[i - 1L]
        x[i - 1L] <- x[i]
        x[i] <- tmp
      }
    }
  }
  x
}

bubble(num)
#>  [1] 96 87 74 45 37 26 14 11  6  4

bubble(num, FALSE)
#>  [1]  4  6 11 14 26 37 45 74 87 96
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>